# How to work with data in dynamically created column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, calculated-columns

Sometimes you want to append a string or int to the data in a given column, such as `SELECT 1005 + ID FROM Users` (where you'd be adding 1005 to the ID column data). How can this be done for columns that are created dynamically?

The following works:

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       (SELECT Email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.ID = d.ID) AS Email,
       Address
FROM data d
```

But adding the following new line creates the error `Invalid column name "Email"`:

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       (SELECT Email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.ID = d.ID) AS Email,
       Email + ' testing ' AS Test, /* New line that causes error */
       Address
FROM data d
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reference an alias. You can repeat the expression (usually unwise performance-wise and/or undesirable syntax-wise) or use a subquery / CTE. And why are you using a correlated subquery instead of a join?

```
SELECT ID, Name, Email, Email + ' testing' AS Test, Address
FROM
(
  SELECT d.ID, d.Name, e.Email, d.Address
  FROM dbo.data AS d
  INNER JOIN dbo.Emails AS e
  ON e.ID = d.ID
) AS x;
```

...or a CTE...

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT d.ID, d.Name, e.Email, d.Address
  FROM dbo.data AS d
  INNER JOIN dbo.Emails AS e
  ON e.ID = d.ID
)
SELECT ID, Name, Email, Email + ' testing' AS Test, Address
  FROM x;
```

Comment: So what is a possible solution?

Comment: The example I gave above was just that: an example. The kind of query I'm working with is quite complex and cannot use a join to do what I need, that is why I am asking about this.

Comment: @reformed well it would be the same thing: your original query would do inside the `( )` part, and you would reference the alias from the outer scope. You can't reference the alias at the same level.

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion helped steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that should not be done in a subquery, use a join instead. Correlated subqueries in genral are a poor technique as they can be performance killers and they are only rarely needed. They should be a technique of last resort not a technique of first resort.

```
SELECT ID,
       Name,
       Email,
       Email + ' testing ' AS Test, 
       Address
FROM data d 
JOIN Emails e ON e.ID = d.ID
```

If everyone won't have an email use a left join. If there are multipel email addresses then you may need some addtional criteria to filter on or you may need to use aggregae functions.

Comment: The OP said the actual query is much more complex, and the subqueries are required in the more complex version. You need to alias the columns (duplicate column of ID at least).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem your having is that you are trying to reference something that is 'Out of scope'. When you use a subquery in the select statement the subqueries tables are only accessible for that item. That access does not carry over to other items in the select statement. So, this should work for you (if it's ugly and it works, it's not ugly).

```
SELECT ID,
   Name,
   (SELECT Email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.ID = d.ID) AS Email,
   (SELECT Email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.ID = d.ID) 
      + ' testing ' AS Test, 
   Address
FROM data d
```

Comment: Do you think it's wise to repeat a correlated subquery, of all things, knowing that SQL Server could very well be forced to evaluate it multiple times?

Comment: Just noting: The other respondents where correct in stating that if you do this a lot a join is a better solution, subqueries will take more processing power

Comment: @Aaron: no, I think a join would be better and more efficient. This solution is ugly but it should correct the error reformed is having without using a join.

Comment: I mean the approach of repeating the expression (any expression) in general, but especially when the OP is forced to use a correlated subquery (as he explained in comments above). Repeating the expression is certainly *a* way to do it, but it is the least optimal in terms of complexity (imagine the expression is a lot more complicated than this), and may be least optimal in terms of perf, too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Using the optimal solution may be ideal if he has to run the query hundred's or thousand's of times daily. But if he is only running it once and does not want to have to refactor the query for joins this should work. I had a query that had a hundred of these sub-queries in the select statement (de-normalizing a table so I could analyze it). Since I only had to run it a few times a day I wasn't concerned with optimization.